# I got error when i typing "npm start", how to fix it?

Tags: npm, npm-start

[image]

I got error when i typing "npm start", how to fix this ?

thanks in advance..

Comment: Please copy the output of the command into your question as text, as an image won't be searchable.

Answer (score -1):

There is no `package.json` in /Users/Witech02. Most likely you run this in the wrong directory, since it is the user directory and not some project subdirectory. Or the file has been removed.

Comment: i think i accidentally deleted it, because previously it still works well.. how to fix it then sir ?